# How to read / write a null terminated string from stream while downloading from FTP

Tags: c#, ftp, download

I'm working on a Updater that downloads a updatelist.xml file containing information (hash code, file name, and file directory) about files on a FTP server.

It then gets the information of those files on the local computer and if they are different (based on hash code) the updater proceeds to download the updated file from the ftp server.

That works great, but I'm having a little problem when it comes to txt files. Basically when I'm writing the file, it doesn't writes the null terminated string, for example:

This is the file on FTP server:

```
"Come Lads! How does things go?
I see my youth in you and it makes
```

This is the same file once it has been downloaded to the local computer:

```
"Come Lads! How does things go?I see my youth in you and it makes
```

I've been searching information on internet but I'm not understanding how to fix this.

This is a piece of the code, which I think is the important part.

```
FileStream file;
file = File.Open(downloadFilePath, FileMode.Create);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 30];

int read;
long downloaded = 0;
while ((read = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    downloaded += read;

    string text = string.Format("Descargando archivo {0} de {1}: {2} - {3} / {4}", curFiles, totalFiles,
        xn["Name"].InnerText, BytesToString(downloaded), BytesToString(contentLength));

    label_progreso.Text = text;

    progressBar2.Value = (int)ProgressBarValue(downloaded, contentLength);

    file.Write(buffer, 0, read);
}
```

Clearly the problem is that when the program creates and writes the file it does not writes the null terminated string.

What I'm missing?

I've found info using webclient.download instead of FtpWebRequest, I've tried that but it doesn't work either.

Comment: What makes you think that null characters have anything to do with your problem? C# doesn't care about null-termination. A string in C# is an arbitrary sequence of characters - including null.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your reply. The main problem is that because of the way that the program is downloading (writing) the text file in the local pc, it does not has the same hash code of the file on the ftp server therefore everytime I open the updater it downloads the same files even when they have been downloaded.

As you say maybe the problem is other, but I can't find the way I should download the file with the original format, something important if the hash code must be identical to the original file.

(Sorry for my english)

Comment: Did you try the [WebClient.DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144194.aspx) method? Try that, and look at the number of bytes in the target file, then check it byte by byte. Are both source and target systems running Windows? If not, then there may simply not _be_ an equivalent: the newline characters might be different, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You should always close `FileStream` objects. Try [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement

```
using(FileStream file = File.Open(downloadFilePath, FileMode.Create))
{
    //code
}
```